# How to ask the user to input a whole number between 1 and 50, and then the applet prints out a line of this number of stars

Tags: javascript, java, loops, for-loop, applet

Ask the user to input a whole number between 1 and 50. The applet then  prints out a line of this number of stars.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ForDemo extends Applet implements ActionListener{

     TextField num;
     int num1;
     Label prompt;

     public void init(){
         prompt = new Label("Enter a number that is less than 50");
         num = new TextField(10);
         add(prompt);
         add(num);
         num.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(num.getText());
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
    //For values of an int I from 1, 2, .., 12 the loop evaluates 6*i.
    //Note that the for loop variable can be defined in the loop.
    //Note also that the loop variable is used to position the printout.

    for (num1 = 1; num1 <=250; num1 ++)
        g.drawString("6 times " + num1 + " = " + 6*num1, 25, 25+20*num1);

    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When I typed a number into the textfield, nothing appear

Comment: it doesn't look like this code is complete, repaint does not exist and paint uses a loop to do some multiplication by 6

Comment: I don't really know how to print out a line of star based on user's input

Answer (score 0):

Typing is not enough. You need to take action and you do that either by pressing enter or you add some button. Or you create thread that reads inpup in some intervals.

Comment: so i need to add a button, so when the button is pressed, it will print a line of star.

Comment: Also, you need to fix this:  

`for (num1 = 1; num1 <=250; num1 ++)  
            g.drawString("6 times " + num1 + " = " + 6*num1, 25, 25+20*num1);`  

You will end up always with same output because you always go from 1 to 250 no matter what you give it. So, either have another variable to increment here or something. It works but your code prints same thing each time because its written to do that.

Comment: Can i ask how to change it?

Comment: Something like this:

        for (int i = num1; i <=250; i ++)
            g.drawString("6 times " + i + " = " + 6*i, 25, 25+20*i);

Question is what do you want? What is your goal based on input?